# Find min 3 values and max 3 values in array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a problem about finding 3 min values and 3 max values in the number array. Even if I correctly find all these 3 max values in the array, I couldn't get the min3 value.

Here is the nums array `[-100,-98,-1,2,3,4]`

min3 is normally -1, but I get 4.

How can I fix it?

Here is the code snippet shown below.

```
int max1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int max2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int max3 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        
int min1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int min2 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int min3 = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
        
if(nums.length >= 3) {
            
    for(Integer value : nums) {
        int current = value;
                
                
        // Max
        if(current > max1) {
            max3 = max2;
            max2 = max1;
            max1 = current;
        }else if(current > max2){
            max3 = max2;
            max2 = current;
        }else {
            max3 = current;
        }
                
        // min
        if(min1 > current) {
            min3 = min2;
            min2 = min1;
            min1 = current;
        }
        else if(min2 > current) {
            min3 = min2;
            min2 = current; 
        }else {
            min3 = current; 
        }
                
    }
            
    System.out.println("max1 : " + max1 + " , max2 : " + max2 + " , max3 : " + max3);
    System.out.println("min1 : " + min1 + " , min2 : " + min2 + " , min3 : " + min3);
                
}
```

Here is the console output shown below.

```
max1 : 4 , max2 : 3 , max3 : 2
min1 : -100 , min2 : -98 , min3 : 4
```

Comment: why do you do `max3 = current;` everytime? There is no `if` that checks the value against `current`.

Comment: else {
            max3 = current;
        } you  really should check whether or not you need to overwrite max3 here

Comment: @f1sh `max3 = current;` is only valid for else case.

Comment: @leonardkraemer I edited my post to show nums array.

Comment: Try using Arrays.sort() then print the first three and last three entries.

Comment: @kiwiron I tried to do that except for the usage of `Arrays.sort()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution below.

```
if(nums.length >= 3) {
            
            for(Integer value : nums) {
                int current = value;
                
                
                // Max
                if(current > max1) {
                    max3 = max2;
                    max2 = max1;
                    max1 = current;
                }else if(current > max2){
                    max3 = max2;
                    max2 = current;
                }else if(current > max3){
                    max3 = current;
                }
                
                // min
                if(min1 > current) {
                    min3 = min2;
                    min2 = min1;
                    min1 = current;
                }
                else if(min2 > current) {
                    min3 = min2;
                    min2 = current; 
                }else if(min3 > current){
                    min3 = current; 
                }
                
            }
            
            System.out.println("max1 : " + max1 + " , max2 : " + max2 + " , max3 : " + max3);
            System.out.println("min1 : " + min1 + " , min2 : " + min2 + " , min3 : " + min3);
            
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't check if `current < min3`

Comment: And so for `current>max3`

Answer (score 0):

Solution for the problem  *"find N max / N min"* based on N variables and manually implemented conditional logic is inflexible and can be error-prone.

If you need to find, let's say, `10` min/max values instead of `3` it would become totally unmanageable.

Instead of the swarm of variable, you can maintain two [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)s. Before adding attempting to add a new element to the queue you would need to check it its size and compare the next element against the root-element of the queue.

That's how it might be implemented:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {8, 5, 7, 8, -3, 5, -5, 9, 12, 18};
    
    Comparator<Integer> minComp = Comparator.reverseOrder();

    Queue<Integer> min = new PriorityQueue<>(minComp);
    Queue<Integer> max = new PriorityQueue<>();
    
    for (int next: arr) {
        tryAdd(min, minComp, 3, next);
        tryAdd(max, Comparator.naturalOrder(),3, next);
    }

    System.out.println(min);
    System.out.println(max);
}

public static void tryAdd(Queue<Integer> queue, Comparator<Integer> comp,
                          int size, int next) {
    
    if (queue.size() == size && comp.compare(next, queue.peek()) > 0) queue.poll();
    if (queue.size() < size) queue.add(next);
}
```

*Output:*

```
[5, -3, -5]
[9, 12, 18]
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/xoc)

Comment: Min values are wrong.

Comment: @S.N Sorry, amended.

Comment: You forgot to define minComp

Comment: @S.N Sorry for not being careful, fixed. Now it should be working fine. It's a simplified version of a more versatile code for similar tasks.

Comment: You inserted minComp into min but min defined twice in your code snippet.

Comment: @S.N Fixed as well. Sometimes writing code without IDE might cause bug (I'm currently out of my machine), verified the solution [online](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/xoc).

Answer (score 0):

This will find the minimum and maximum numbers!!!

```
    for (int n : nums) {
         if (n > max1) {
              max3 = max2;
              max2 = max1;
              max1 = n;
         } else if (n > max2) {
              max3 = max2;
              max2 = n;
         } else if (n > max3) {
              max3 = n;
         }

         if (n < min1) {
              min2 = min1;
              min1 = n;
         } else if (n < min2) {
              min2 = n;
         }
    }
```

Comment: Pardon me, but I don't see how your answer is any different than the accepted answer.